# Conditional sum in Excel or Libreoffice calc

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice

[image]

As an example, in the table above, I want to populate the empty column titled 'Totals' with the corresponding sum of all the Values in the left tables 'Values' column belonging to the category corresponding to the right.

I'm used to programming so usually I would write a conditional for loop with a bunch of if else statements, but I am not sure how to do this in a spreadsheet program.

I assume I must either use a if statement or conditional formatting or a macro, but I'm not sure at all how to implement these.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just FYI, conditional formatting refers to changing the appearance of a cell based on content, so that wouldn't apply to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for
[image]

The formula for ease of copy-paste is added below

```
=SUMIF($B$4:$C$12,D4,$C$4:$C$12)
```

*Note: If you are new to excel formulas and wondering about the $ signs in the formulas - read about relative and absolute cell addressing [here](http://www.terryscomputertips.com/computers/howto-using-excel-how-to-use-absolute-addressing/)*

Comment: in words: if the members of column B equal a value (chosen from col D), sum the corresponding value in column C for each true evaluation.

Note columns run from B to E in this answer.

Comment: Excellent, I understand and got my spreadsheet to work. Thanks guys!

Comment: The first parameter should only contain the numbers to be tested (i.e. the Category column), not the values. So $B$4:$C$12 should be $B$4:$B$12. Test by changing the topmost value from 100 to 1.

Comment: Actually, changing the test value from 100 to 5 is even more fun. Sum for category 5 changes, but only by 1, illustrating that only the top left corner of the range specified by the 3rd parameter matters - other values are determined dynamically. So the third parameter can be rewritten as only "$C$4", although that makes the formula less readable IMHO.